# I am not able to edit the input values in Semantic UI React. I used onChange but it is not working. All the other functions are working Perfectly

Tags: reactjs, forms, onchange, semantic-ui-react

> Here I set the initial state and the target state using react hooks. In the from component I used Semantic UI React from to create the form used value in input to set some default values that has been already entered through the form. Used onChange to edit the values but it is not working.But the onChange is working perfectly.

`Parent Component`

```
const ParentPane = (props) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [appName, setAppName] = useState([{ appName: props?.rowEditData?.appName }]);
const [pattern, setPattern] = useState("");
const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
const [parentData, setParentData] = useState({
    appName: "",
    pattern: "",
    desc: ""
});
```

`Form Component`

```
<Form size="large" inverted className="parentStyle">
        
            <div>
                <Form.Input
                    fluid
                    id="app"
                    name="appName"
                    label="Application Name"
                    value={props?.rowEditData.appName}
                    onChange={(event) => setAppName(event.target.value)}
                />
                <Form.Input
                    fluid
                    id="path"
                    name="pattern"
                    label="Request Path"
                    placeholder="eg: /home"
                    value={props?.rowEditData.pattern}
                    onChange={(event) => setPattern(event.target.value)}
                />
                <Form.Input
                    fluid
                    path="des"
                    name="desc"
                    label="Description"
                    value={props?.rowEditData.description}
                    onChange={(event) => setDesc(event.target.value)}
                />
                <Button
                    className="submitButton"
                    onClick={(event) => saveOrUpdateMock(event, "UPDATE")}
                    style={style.labelStyle}
                >
                    Save
                </Button>
            </div>
```

Comment: I am running into this problem too, can someone help?